# writing an API that wraps Spring MongoDB repositories

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to create a generic class that will interact with multiple Spring MongoDB repositories.  The current code I have compile but blows up with a NULL Exception because both of the repositories are NULL.

Here is my setup, I can't find any documentation that would ensure the autowiring in the  wrapper class.  Is there something that I am missing that will execute the autowiring.  I am using gradle and I added the dependency based off the basic spring mongo project.
Thanks

### InstructorDBRepository.java

```
package courseSystem;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface InstructorDBRepository extends MongoRepository<InstructorDB, String> {

    InstructorDB save(InstructorDB saved);
    void delete(InstructorDB deleted);
    List<InstructorDB> findAll();

}
```

### DBinterface.java

```
package courseSystem;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DBinterface {
    @Autowired
    private AcademicRecordDBRepository AcademicRecordRepository;

    @Autowired
    private InstructorDBRepository InstructorRepository;


    public DBinterface() {}


    public void deleteAllTables()
    {
        AcademicRecordRepository.deleteAll();
        InstructorRepository.deleteAll();;
    }

    //Some additional functions
}
```

Comment: add suitable @Component annotation into DBinterface  class.

Comment: And PLEASE: (1) use constructor injection, (2) don't name fields with starting capital letter. It is not C# ;)